# i need to add columns in some table of Nextcloud for customization,how should i do it properly?

Tags: php, owncloud, nextcloud

I need to add columns in some table of `Nextcloud` for customization.

How should i do it properly?

Like where to start, can't find anything like this on the docs.

**For example:**

If I want to add a logo column for the groups table,
the ajax leads to

```
apps/provisioning_api/lib/Controller/GroupsController
```

it gets an instance of `IGroupManager` passes in at the construction to do things like `createGroup`, but I can't find out where the instance of `IGroupManager` came from.

Comment: nextcloud version is 18.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by creat an app using Migration to add columns and using a customized backend.

***thanks for the editing.***